# Closing a JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog window itself

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, joptionpane

```
final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(this, chooser, "Browse",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
        new Object[]{}, null);
            chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {        
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if(e.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION))

                        System.out.println("File selected: " +
 chooser.getSelectedFile());
                        //code to close here
                    } else { 
                        //code to close here
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code looks weird, but its just a part of my program. Im using full screen `GraphicsDevice`. I put the file chooser in the internal **JOptionPane** to preserve my full screen window. Now I wanted to programmatically close the **JOptionPane** internal itself without closing the whole application in my actionlistener. How can it be done?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"This code looks weird,.."* Yes, it does, as does the requirement. Forget 'what' for the moment & answer 'why?'. What is the use-case for this functionality - or the feature provided?  *"..but its just a part of my program."*  Somehow that is not reassuring.

Answer (score 0):

When you call showInternalOptionDialog, you cannot easily access the reference to the dialog. You could add options, ie. use

```
new Object[] { "Browse", "Cancel" }
```

instead of

```
new Object[]{}
```

but then you would end up having two sets of buttons. I think there is no easy way to use showInternalOptionDialog with JFileChooser. I would suggest to create JInternalFrame yourself.

```
final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(chooser, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[0], null);
final JInternalFrame dialog = pane.createInternalFrame(this, "Dialog Frame");
chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
            System.out.println("File selected: "
                    + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        dialog.setVisible(false);
    }
});
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Also in your code snippet you are invoking addActionListener after showInternalOptionDialog. The showInternalOptionDialog invocation will return only after you close the dialog, so the ActionListener will be created too late. You need to first addActionListener and then show the dialog.